# .glsl files and xcode projects

Tags: xcode, opengl

So I just started with opengl this semester and we started off using the deprecated primitives etc. (old openGL) and had no issue running within xcode. Now that we are using shader files, like .glsl files, xcode just will not run programs, but in terminal they compile and run with no issue. I have my .c and .h files in the project aswell as the .glsl files. Im assuming xcode has to see the .glsl files someway but im lost. Any ideas?

Comment: Will you share any code with us? It's pretty hard to spot the problem if we don't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Im assuming xcode has to see the .glsl files someway but im lost.

No, XCode does not have to "see" the "glsl" files. Technically there's not GLSL "file" format at all. GLSL is a programming language. And it's your program's job to *somehow* deliver GLSL shader source code to OpenGL. That can be from a file, but just as well dynamically created at runtime.

> Any ideas?

Show us your actual code?